# REGEXP_SUBSTR throws 'pcre_exec: match limit exceeded' from regexp

Tags: mariadb

I have a  table account with a login field
I want to extract clean email from this login field

My test is :

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_test;
CREATE TABLE   tmp_test AS (
    SELECT id,
           REGEXP_SUBSTR(login, '[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})') clean_login,
           login
    FROM account
    LIMIT 5000
)
```

This works.

If I remove limit : Got error 'pcre_exec: match limit exceeded' from regexp

I am looking for MariaDB option to increase this limit, without success.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Problem is coming from a record with login like : user@very-very-very-long-domain-name.con

Comment: That's not a good regular expression for email anyway (too restrictive of allowed characters, failing on 3+ part domains). Show some sample data for login; what else is there that you are trying to get rid of.

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB doesn't have an option to increase the limit size, and there are no plans to add it.

See also comment from [MDEV-8637: sysvar to control pcre match limit.](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-8637):

"*With a too much complex regular expression, performance becomes too bad anyway.
One should consider rewriting regular expressions in a more efficient way, or use some other text processing functions.*"